# Zero and pole of transfer function spaced for one octave

Tags: transfer-function

Here is my task:

Find ratio R1/R2 so that zero and pole of transfer function are spaced for one octave.

[image]

I found zero and pole, but what "spaced for one octave" means?

[image]

Comment: Did you consider looking up [octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_(electronics)) on Wiki before asking this question?

Comment: Sure, but although I know definition, I don't know how to apply it in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An octave is a factor of 2 in frequency.

If two frequencies \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$ are spaced by an octave then either

$$\frac{f_1}{f_2} = 2$$

or

$$\frac{f_1}{f_2} = \frac{1}{2}$$